# How to scrape multiple tables that are without IDs or Class using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape this webpage using R : http://zipnet.in/index.php?page=missing_mobile_phones_search&criteria=browse_all (All the pages)

I'm new to programming. And everywhere I've looked, tables are mostly identified with IDs or Divs or Class. On this page there's none. Data is stored in Table format. How should I scrape it?

This is what I did :

```
 library(rvest)
 webpage <- read_html("http://zipnet.in/index.php    
 page=missing_mobile_phones_search&criteria=browse_all")

 tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")

 head(tbls)

tbls_ls <- webpage %>%
html_nodes("table") %>%
          .[9:10] %>%

html_table(fill = TRUE)

colnames(tbls_ls[[1]]) <- c("Mobile Make", "State", "District",
                         "Police Station", "Status", "Mobile Type(GSM/CDMA)", 
                         "FIR/DD/GD Dat")
```

Comment: did that achieve the results you wanted it to? if so, then it's a completely good and valid approach.

Comment: No, this code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape the table data by targeting the css id of each table. It looks like each page is composed of 3 different tables pasted one after another. Two of the tables have `#AutoNumber15` css id while the third (in the middle) has the `#AutoNumber16` css id.

I put a simple code example that should get you started in the right direction.

```r
suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressMessages(library(rvest))

# define function to scrape the table data from a page
get_page <- function(page_id = 1) {
  # default link
  link <- "http://zipnet.in/index.php?page=missing_mobile_phones_search&criteria=browse_all&Page_No="
  # build link
  link <- paste0(link, page_id)

  # get tables data
  wp <- read_html(link)
  wp %>% 
    html_nodes("#AutoNumber16, #AutoNumber15") %>% 
    html_table(fill = TRUE) %>% 
    bind_rows()
}

# get the data from the first three pages 
iter_page <- 1:3
# this is just a progress bar
pb <- progress_estimated(length(iter_page))

# this code will iterate over pages 1 through 3 and apply the get_page() 
# function defined earlier. The Sys.sleep() part is used to pause the code
# after each iteration so that the sever is not overloaded with requests.
map_df(iter_page, ~ {
  pb$tick()$print()
  df <- get_page(.x)
  Sys.sleep(sample(10, 1) * 0.1)
  as_tibble(df)
})
#> # A tibble: 72 x 4
#>                       X1           X2                         X3
#>                    <chr>        <chr>                      <chr>
#>  1      FIR/DD/GD Number       000165                      State
#>  2        FIR/DD/GD Date   17/08/2017                   District
#>  3 Mobile Type(GSM/CDMA)          GSM             Police Station
#>  4           Mobile Make   SAMSUNG J2              Mobile Number
#>  5   Missing/Stolen Date   23/04/2017                IMEI Number
#>  6           Complainant   AKEEL KHAN Complainant Contact Number
#>  7                Status Stolen/Theft Report Date/Time on ZIPNET
#>  8                  <NA>         <NA>                       <NA>
#>  9      FIR/DD/GD Number   FIR No 37/                      State
#> 10        FIR/DD/GD Date   17/08/2017                   District
#> # ... with 62 more rows, and 1 more variables: X4 <chr>
```

Comment: Thanks much. What is this section doing? pb <- progress_estimated(length(iter_page))

map_df(iter_page, ~ {
  pb$tick()$print()
  df <- get_page(.x)
  Sys.sleep(sample(10, 1) * 0.1)
  as_tibble(df)
})

Comment: I added a few additional comments to clarify the code. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Its great.

Comment: How do i get this code to show up the entire table on the first page: "with 62 more rows, and 1 more variables: X4 <chr>" I'd like to get this on a spreadsheet for analysis. Can I just copy the table produced here on the spreadsheet?

Comment: You can use `write.csv()` function to write the result to a csv file that you can later open in Excel.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.